# How to import a .sql file while starting mysql service on ubuntu OS

Tags: mysql, linux, docker, ubuntu

After installing mysql on ubuntu I'd like to  start the mysql service with following command which will start the service and also it will create the schema and tables.

```
service mysql start && mysql -u root -e "CREATE DATABASE organzation; use organzation; CREATE TABLE employee(Email varchar(30) NOT NULL)"
```

Now suppose I have a file.sql file, how to import this file.sql while starting the mysql service.
PS:    **mysql -u username -p database_name < file.sql**   this doesn't work while starting the mysql service.

Comment: Are you doing this in docker ?

Comment: @Dhirendra Exaclty. But the main motive is to know how to import a .sql file while starting a mysql service.

Comment: I doubt, chaining would work.  You need to find a way to wait for mysql service to be up & running.

Comment: Are you getting any error ?

Answer (score 0):

From [mysql Docker](https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql/):

> ## Initializing a fresh instance
>
> When a container is started for the first time, a new database with the specified name will be created and initialized with the provided configuration variables. Furthermore, it will execute files with extensions .sh, .sql and .sql.gz that are found in /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d. Files will be executed in alphabetical order. You can easily populate your mysql services by mounting a SQL dump into that directory and provide custom images with contributed data. SQL files will be imported by default to the database specified by the MYSQL_DATABASE variable.

You just need to put your `.sql` file(s) in `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d` directory.

Comment: Can I use multiple .sh file as ENTRYPOINT  in the Dockerfile?

Comment: No.  Are you using mysql docker image, or installing mysql in ubuntu docker image ?

Comment: If you are installing in ubuntu image, then this won't work for you.

Comment: I am installing mysql on ubuntu docker image.  So, want to import a .sql file with the "start mysql service" command.